# Express - Update does not take effect on the database MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My update doesn't seem to work. Not a Database issue as my delete works.

This is my Update route.

Can you please help? I am using console.log to print the values in the console. All getting the right valies.

I have tried logging through console.log printing values during the "update".

```
C:\Personal\Books\Trials>node app.js
Trials is running on port 3000
Success Update
5cc86fa0b5e2143684378877
Jim4
{ _id: 5cc86fa0b5e2143684378877,
  fieldname: 'Jim3',
  fieldtype: 'string',
  fieldinputtype: 'textbox',
  __v: 0 }
```

```
app.put("/adminstudy/:id",function(req,res){
    studyfields.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.fieldname, function(err, returnedstudyfield){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/adminstudy");
        } else {
            console.log("Success Update");
            console.log(req.params.id);
            console.log(req.body.fieldname);
            console.log(returnedstudyfield);
            res.redirect("/adminstudy");
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my form that sends to the update route:

```
            <form action="/adminstudy/<%= editedstudyfield._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fieldname" value="<%= editedstudyfield.fieldname %>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="fieldtype">
                        <option value="string">Text</option>
                        <option value="number">Number</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="fieldinputtype">
                        <option value="textbox">Text Box</option>
                        <option value="Textarea">Text Area</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" type="submit">UPDATE THIS STUDY FIELD</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I was expecting it to update, but it doesn't. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "update" parameter should be an object of key-value pairs:

```
 { fieldname: req.body.fieldname }
```

(it surprises me that it does not error though)

Answer (score 0):

You send only a string to mongo.
I guess you need to send `{fieldname: req.body.fieldname}`

```
studyfields.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {fieldname: req.body.fieldname} ...
```